# When resolve returning $firebaseArray needs return of $firebaseObject service first?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I recently discovered [David East's firebase blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/the-single-biggest-angular-and-firebase-code-smell-and-how-to-fix-it-a0d1ef96ca65#.7adk82yu2) and have started to move my $loaded usage from my controllers to my resolves for each view. One issue that has come up involves a situation where I'm retrieving a $firebaseArray with a firebaseRef which contains something from another firebase database call. My ref for the second part would be something like this:

```
var chatRef = firebase.database().ref('messages/'+thisGroup.groupId+'/main');
```

Is this a situation where I can only unwrap one promise through the resolve, or am I close doing something like this (ActiveGroup is a service which returns a $firebaseObject of the user's currently selected group):

```
.state('tab.chats-main', {
      url: '/chats/main',
      cache: true,
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chatsTopic.html',
          controller: 'ChatsTopicCtrl'
        }
      },
    resolve: {
      currentAuth: authRequire,
      posts: function($firebaseArray, currentAuth, ActiveGroup){
        var thisGroup = ActiveGroup(currentAuth.uid);
          thisGroup.$loaded().then(function(){
          var chatRef = firebase.database().ref('messages/'+thisGroup.groupId+'/main');
          return $firebaseArray(chatRef.limitToLast(100)).$loaded();
        })    
      }
    }
})
```

And then here is where I am injecting posts in the controller:

```
    .controller('ChatsTopicCtrl', function($scope, thisGroup, posts, profile, chatName, chatMessages, currentAuth, ActiveGroup, $cordovaCamera, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicModal, $ionicActionSheet, $timeout,$state, moment) {

console.log("what are posts? ",posts); // posts is undefined
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your actual question is not clear.

Comment: @theblindprophet Hmm, between my example and the article I referenced it feels pretty clear what I'm asking but I'm happy to clarify if you can be more specific.

Comment: Are you asking if its possible? Does it work? Are there errors?

Comment: Got it - using the resolve code above where I'm chaining promises, I was injecting "posts" into my controller and it was coming back undefined. When I added a console log after the first $loaded (for thisGroup) it was showing that the first promise worked correctly. Basically, I am having async issues where my controller is not waiting for that second $loaded and "posts" is undefined in my controller.

Comment: Please include where the `resolve` is located inside. The also provide how `posts` gets called. I believe I can fix the issue with that.

Comment: @theblindprophet Thanks, just updated the original question with more code.

Answer (score 0):

So I found something that works but I'm not sure if it's the best practice. By doing each firebase call separately (and in the proper order), this seems to do the trick:

```
.state('tab.chats-main', {
  url: '/chats/main',
  cache: true,
  views: {
    'tab-chats': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chatsTopic.html',
      controller: 'ChatsTopicCtrl'
    }
  },
  resolve: {
    currentAuth: authRequire,
    thisGroup: function(ActiveGroup, currentAuth){
      return ActiveGroup(currentAuth.uid).$loaded();
    },
    posts: function($firebaseArray, thisGroup){     
      var chatRef = firebase.database().ref('messages/'+thisGroup.groupId+'/main');
      return $firebaseArray(chatRef.limitToLast(100)).$loaded();    
    }       
}
})
```

And then the controller where you inject it:

```
    .controller('ChatsTopicCtrl', function($scope, thisGroup, posts, profile, chatName, chatMessages, currentAuth, ActiveGroup, $cordovaCamera, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicModal, $ionicActionSheet, $timeout,$state, moment) {

console.log("what is posts? ",posts); // gives proper result
```

If there is a better/more recommended way of doing this, I'd still really appreciate hearing it.